# lightdm не могу ввести пароль после пробуждения

Tags: linux, lightdm

Если ноутбук отправляется спать с русской раскладкой, то после его пробуждения не могу ввести пароль в форме ввода lightdm. При этом язык ввода показан, как en. пробовал вводить после переключения на русский, с капсом, итд.

Порылся по форумам и понял, что полностью эту форму отрубить непросто, проще задизейблить её на время. Чтож, мне не сложно ввести пароль, только как сделать так, чтобы не беспокоиться о том, в какой раскладке ноутбук отправляется спать?

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/1311403